# LWC Data Table with a specific formatting

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, slds-styling-hooks

I am implementing lightning-datatable to view my data, but want a red border if closed date is passed.
Please refer below screen shot for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styling to particular cells, you will need to add a field with the class name that contains the desired styling for the cell to the data.

The documentation has an example based on the Industry Type field - see [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types_styling#:~:text=To%20apply%20styling%20to%20particular%20rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types_styling#:%7E:text=To%20apply%20styling%20to%20particular%20rows)

Comment: Hey, ya i checked that one but i am only able to change the text color border is not coming by using this.